# Cycles Line style node editor keyframe or driver not working

Tags: node-editor

I'm using blender 2.79b in cycles. I can see freestyle after rendering and manage freestyle line set and freestyle line style by the render layers tab. When I activate "Use node" in node editor + line style button or in render layer tab, freestyle line style, texture I can see the node (eg. line style output).

I'm tring to keyframe (eg. alpha) and set 1 in frame 1 and 0 in frame 2. But when I set the second keyframe on frame 2 the value setted on frame 1 change to the last setted value (in the case 0). So seems keyframe don't work

I try also to manage via driver but after adding driver, manually create later (as I do usually for other) I cant see the driver in the graph editor, driver button.

Is it possible to manage line style node?

My current workaround is to disable use node and keyframe using the keyframe on the freestyle line style panel.

Another question:
Using node editor for line style i can't see many shaders as i can find when i use node for material (eg. i'm looking for emission).

Is it possible to use them?

Thanks